# Get reference to "current" section

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I'd like to write a command to get a reference to the "current" section provided (the term is all wrong, but the example will clarify).

The idea is something along the lines of:

```
\getcurrentref{chapter}
```

or

```
\getcurrentref{subsubsection}
```

and so on.

A section is considered "current" at a given point if said point is within the "scope" of said section.

Example:

```
\chapter{A}
  % point (1)
  \section{A.A}
    % point (2)
  \section{A.B}
    % point (3)
    \subsection{A.B.A}
      % point (4)
```

the only "living" section at point `(1)` is `chapter`, the only "living" sections at points `(2)` and `(3)` are `chapter` and `section`, and the only "living" sections at point `(4)` are `chapter`, `section` and `subsection`.

I hope I could explain myself (it's tricky).

PS: in case of trying to get the reference to a non-"living" section, the command should return `??` (this is just to have a standard graceful way of saying *"no such section alive"*).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that subordinate "sections" are reset to 0 by larger ones (so `\chapter` resets `\section` and so on), you just have to look at the counters `chapter`, `section`, etc., and check whether they're nonzero:

```
\documentclass{book} % For {chapter}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\getcurrentref[1]{%
 \ifnumequal{\value{#1}}{0}
  {??}
  {\the\value{#1}}%
}    
\begin{document}
 Chapter: \getcurrentref{chapter}

 \chapter{I}
 \tracingmacros=1\tracingonline=1
 Chapter: \getcurrentref{chapter}\\
 \tracingmacros=0
 Section: \getcurrentref{section}

 \section{i}
 Chapter: \getcurrentref{chapter}\\
 Section: \getcurrentref{section}\\
 Subsection: \getcurrentref{subsection}

 \section{ii}
 Section: \getcurrentref{section}

 \subsection{a}
 Subsection: \getcurrentref{subsection}
\end{document}
```

This should be expandable, by the way.  I only use `etoolbox` for the handy conditional, which in a more complicated situation might be simpler than a TeX primitive (e.g. with respect to nesting or expansion order).  Here, it's optional.

**Edit:** I now use `\value{#1}` rather than `\csname c@#1\endcsname` for the number, as one would like.  As egreg says, it is expandable (actually, it expands just to this).  However, it does expand rather unpredictably in the sense that it is equivalent to a count *register*, not to an actual number, and so the part of the macro that actually prints the value needs a `\the` to avoid weird errors.  In my case, I was seeing "Missing number inserted" in the expansion of `\\`, which (upon tracing) appeared to be related to `\protect`.

Comment: You can say `\ifnumeq{\value{section}}{0}{true}{false}`; `\ifnumeq` will eventually do `\ifnum\value{section}=0` which is perfectly legal; `\value` *is* expandable, since it is a macro and `\ifnum` will trigger its expansion, which is `\csname c@section\endcsname`; `\ifnum` will continue and find `\c@section` which is a legal (unexpandable) token after `\ifnum`. The fact that `\c@section` is unexpandable has nothing to do with the complete expandability of the macro `\getcurrentref`: it will disappear when TeX performs the conditional test.

Comment: @egreg: really?  That's bizarre, since I was getting some error involving `\protect` when I tried to do just that.  I wonder why.

Comment: I get no error if I plug in `\value{#1}` instead of `\the\csname c@#1\endcsname`. By the way also `\the` is useless: when TeX is looking for a <number>, a count register is good.

Comment: @egreg: Must have been a typo, I guess?  Anyway, thanks for the tip: I am sort of fuzzy on what role registers play.

Comment: When TeX is looking for a number it's satisfied with a constant (a sequence of digits), an alphabetic constant (a character, possibly escaped, preceded by a backquote), a count register, a `\chardef` or `\mathchardef` token. Actually also dimen and skip registers can go there (the value in scaled points would be used). Saying `\the\cnt` will only make TeX work harder, first by expanding `\cnt` to its decimal representation and then gathering again the digits to form the <number>. And `\ifnum1=\the\cnt 1` might give a surprise if `\cnt` has stored the value 0. :)

Comment: Well, it's necessary `\the` for *printing* the value of a counter; better `\arabic{cnt}` than `\the\value{cnt}`, though, from a LaTeXian point of view.

Comment: @egreg: I'll just upvote this comment rather than make any more changes :)

Answer (score 21):

Use `\thechapter`, `\thesection`, etc:

```
\documentclass{report}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\label{chap:first}

\section{First}
\label{sec:first}

This is the chapter number~\thechapter, section~\thesection.

\section{Second}
\label{sec:second}

This is the chapter number~\thechapter, section~\thesection.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There's no notion of "current" level, unless one plugs in one into the sectioning commands. The best one can do is to see if the related counter is zero or not:

```
\newcommand{\getcurrentref}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{#1}=0 ??\else\csname the#1\endcsname\fi
}
```

No packages. This is actually the same as Ryan's answer, but reduced to the essential.