# How to change the numbers on a section?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, syntax

I would like to relabel the numbering on the `\section{}` to match the lecture number. Issue is don't I start the document at lecture 1, hence the discrepancies.

Any help would be most appreciated.

[image: a puzzle]

Comment: What would be the ideal solution? That the other sections don't have a number? Do you really want to number the lectures manually?

Comment: I don't mind manually labelling it if it works... even if I put a '\section*{}' star before the braces then the '\subsection{}' numbers get messed up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something like this:

[image]

You can change the title heading of course, but all subsections will be labeled correctly.  Just make sure you don't have two sections 39....

```
\documentclass{article}



\newcommand{\mysection}[2]{\setcounter{section}{#1}\addtocounter{section}{-1}\section{Lecture #1: #2}}


\begin{document}

\mysection{39}{Systems of Difference and Differential Equations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just want to change the current section's number and changed the command to this:
`\newcommand{\setsectionnumber}[1]{\setcounter{section}{#1}\addtocounter{section}{-1}}`
The following sections will be numbered accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with this approach? Or maybe I don't fully get the question.

> In addition, it would help if you would provide a complete code
>   example and not just a screenshot.

### First Approach

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Unnumbered Section}
\subsection*{Unnumbered SubSection}
\subsection*{Unnumbered SubSection}

\section*{Unnumbered Section}
\subsection*{Unnumbered SubSection}
\subsection*{Unnumbered SubSection}

\section{Lecture 1}
\subsection{ SubSection of Lecture 1}

\section{Lecture 2}
\subsection{ SubSection of Lecture 1}

\section{Lecture 3}
\subsection{ SubSection of Lecture 1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Second Approach (Using the `book` or `report` Document Class and the Chapter Level)

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter Before Lectures}
\section{Section Before Lectures}
\section{Section Before Lectures}

\chapter{Lectures Start Here}
\section{Lecture 1}
\subsection{SubSection of Lecture 1}
\section{Lecture 2}
\subsection{SubSection of Lecture 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Automatic Numbering -- Maybe Related Questions

- [Get reference to "current" section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34702/get-reference-to-current-section)
- [How can I reference the current (sub)section number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141367/how-can-i-reference-the-current-subsection-number)

Comment: The problem is if OP wants to start things off at "Lecture 17", they need to manually change the section counter to the appropriate value.

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying to solve exactly the same problem as well, and I finally found a very neat and easy to use solution. First we define the command `\section` to be some specific phrase like "Lecture" followed by its numbering by doing

```latex
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont \Large \bfseries}
{Lecture\ \thesection}{2.3ex plus .2ex}{} %% Text "Lecture" is what you would like the section number to display with.
\titlespacing{\subsection}{2em}{*1}{*1}
```

Then define the command of setting arbitrary numbering to a specific section manually

```latex
\newcommand{\asection}[2]{
\setcounter{section}{#1}
\addtocounter{section}{-1}
\section{#2}
}
```

Therefore in the document, we could write

```latex
\asection{3}{Dynamics of Gravity}
\label{DG}
...
\asection{7}{Geometric Interpretation of Gravitation}
\label{GIG}

Please read section \eqref{DG} first.
...
\asection{11}{Einstein Field Equation}

Please read section \eqref{GIG} first.
...
```

The output looks pretty

> [image: arbitrary numbering behind section]

Comment: it works for me!. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{9.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

Comment: This works and it's a nice and flexible solution.